# Fread() doesn't read any data

Tags: c

I have a problem with fread(). I'm learning C and I cannot handle problem with function which have to read data from binary file. Below is code of my function:

```
bool deserialize(struct list** lst, const char* filename)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if(!file)
        return false;

    int num = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(i < 10)
    {
        fread(&num, sizeof(int), 1, file);  // <- this not work
        printf("%u\n", num);
        printf("%ld\n", ftell(file));
        i++;
        //list_add_back(num, &(*lst));
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is fread doesn't read anything. The num variable is still 0, the ftell shows that the pointer in file is in the same place (0). The binary file exist (function before i save list in binary file with fwrite, this is next function to do). The content of file are numbers from 1 to 10. Below you can see what xxd show what's in the file:

```
unsigned char linkedlist_bin[] = {
  0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
unsigned int linkedlist_bin_len = 40;
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: And what did `fread` return and what did `perror` say after `fread`?!

Comment: Most system functions return something useful you shouldn't ignore.

Comment: You should read the man page of fread: https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread

Comment: @mch if all else fails read the docs

Comment: Nominally, you shouldn't use `%u` to print an `int`.  That is not, however, the cause of your problem.  I suspect you are reading from an empty file different from the one you think you are reading.  What is the file name passed into the function?  Did you print that out?  Was it an absolute or relative file name?

Comment: Sounds as if the length of the file you read is zero. As do as suggest in the very first comment.

Comment: If you have opened the file for writing, and opened another file handle for reading, they are distinct.  If you haven't closed or flushed the handle that you have open for writing, then the filesystem doesn't know about any of the data.  So the read thinks the file is empty.  Have you closed or flushed the file handle you have open for writing?

Comment: @WilliamPursell You are right! I totally forgot to close the file after writing it in previous function! Now it's working. Thanks a lot and sorry for so stupid question.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Good guess. This was just one more question where the OP didn't tell us everything.

Comment: @WilliamPursell what is OP?

Comment: @andrew_almighty "original post" or "original poster"

Comment: @andrew_almighty Walz was passively suggesting that in the future, you make sure to review what qualifies a good SO question. In this specific case, you failed to test your problem in a minimal capacity, one without other functions indirectly related to your issue. Had you done so, the issue would have been absent, and you could have directed your attention to what you removed in minimization. Secondly, there was additional code in your failing executable that you did not disclose in your post.This made Pursell's achievement even more noteworthy.